# Is there a way to have multiple inline configured ckeditors with single toolbar DOM element

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

An inline configured ckeditor has its toolbar attached to document body. Unless the user didn't focus the editor the toolbar is hidden. If we have multiple inline editors on same page, there will be the same number toolbar DOM elements attached to the body - each one with specific identifier. My question is, if there is a way to have a single toolbar DOM element for multiple inline ckeditors? I know (and I'm using in different context) the shared space plugin which does that, but the drawback is that one should provide an element to which the single toolabar would be attached. That's OK, but it is static and stays at the place where it's placed in the DOM order and I'd like it to be repositioned next to the currently focused editor. 
Seems like I either have to use the default inline behavior or to use the shared space plugin and to reposition the single toolbar instance myself. 
Any ideas on this issue or something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

No, every CKEditor creates its own toolbar. But you can create your own plugin for this which is actually just displaying the toolbar of the active element. I have created one have a look. You do require to configure the your editor config too.

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('grouplabel', {
init : function(editor) {

    function getCorrespondingName(no) {
        var tempNo = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < editor.config.toolbar.length; i++) {
            if (editor.config.toolbar[i].groupName != undefined) {
                if (tempNo == no) {
                    return i;
                }
                tempNo++;
            }

        }
    }

    function toggleGroupDisplay(evt) {
        if (evt.data.isMinimized) {
            resetAllAbsolute();
            $(this).find(".absoluteToolCont").toggleClass("displayNone");
        } else {
            $('.' + evt.data.grpID).each(function() {
                toggleGroupDisplayInd(this)
            });
        }
    }

    function resetAllAbsolute() {
        $(".absoluteToolCont").addClass("displayNone");
    }

    function toggleGroupDisplayInd(obj) {
        var idM = $("#" + obj.id).parent().attr("id");
        $("#" + idM + "> span").toggleClass("displayNone");
        $("#" + idM).toggleClass("toggleMargin");
        $("#groupLabel_" + idM).toggleClass("toggleMargin");
        $("#groupLabelArrowBtn_" + idM).toggleClass("groupLabelArrowDown");
    }

    var openContainerArray = [ "CHARACTER", "TEXT ALIGN" ];

    function createMainGroups() {
        for (var j = 0; j < editor.toolbox.toolbars.length; j++) {

            var grpId = editor.toolbox.toolbars[j].id;
            var conNo = getCorrespondingName(j);

            var isGroup = editor.config.toolbar[conNo].groupNR;
            if (!isGroup) {
                createMainGroup(conNo, grpId);
            }
        }
    }

    function createMainGroup(conNo, grpId) {
        // console.log(conNo, grpId)
        var name = editor.config.toolbar[conNo].groupName[0];
        var className = editor.toolbar[conNo].name;
        var name = editor.config.toolbar[conNo].groupName[0];
        var elementDiv = groupLabelElementDiv(grpId, className);
        var textDiv = "<div class='textGroupLabel'></div>";
        var arrowDiv = "<div  id='groupLabelArrowBtn_" + grpId
                + "' class='groupLabelArrowUp'></div>";

        $("#" + grpId).addClass("editorGroup transitionType");

        if (editor.config.showIconOnly) {
            detachAndMakeAbsolute(grpId);
        }
        $("#" + grpId).prepend(elementDiv);
        $("#groupLabel_" + grpId).append(textDiv);
        if (!editor.config.showIconOnly) {
            $("#groupLabel_" + grpId).append(arrowDiv);
        }
        addNameOrIcon(editor, name, grpId);
        $(" #groupLabel_" + grpId).unbind("click").bind("click", {
            grpID : "groupLabel_" + className,
            isMinimized : editor.config.showIconOnly
        }, toggleGroupDisplay);
        var bool = false;
        if (!editor.config.showIconOnly) {
            for (var k = 0; k < openContainerArray.length; k++) {
                if (name == openContainerArray[k]) {
                    bool = true;
                }
            }
        }
        showGroup(bool, grpId);

    }

    function detachAndMakeAbsolute(grpId) {
        var divId = "absoluteToolCont_" + grpId
        var absoluteDiv = "<div class='displayFlexAbsolute"
                + " absoluteToolCont' id='" + divId + "'></div>";
        $("#" + grpId).prepend(absoluteDiv);
        var detachedDiv = $("#" + grpId + "> span").detach();
        // console.log(detachedDiv)
        detachedDiv.appendTo("#" + divId);
        resetAllAbsolute();
    }

    function showGroup(bool, grpId) {
        if (!bool) {
            $("#" + grpId + "> span").toggleClass("displayNone");
            $("#" + grpId).toggleClass("toggleMargin");
            $("#groupLabel_" + grpId).toggleClass("toggleMargin");
            $("#groupLabelArrowBtn_" + grpId).toggleClass(
                    "groupLabelArrowDown");
        }
    }

    function addNameOrIcon(editor, name, grpId) {
        var groupName = $("#groupLabel_" + grpId + ">.textGroupLabel");
        var divId = "absoluteToolCont_" + grpId
        if (!editor.config.showIconOnly) {
            groupName.text(name);
        } else {
            var clsName = name.replace(/ /g, '');
            var detachedDiv = $("#" + divId).detach();
            $("#groupLabel_" + grpId).prepend(detachedDiv);
            groupName.html("<div class='iconToolbar " + clsName
                    + "'></div>");
            var overFlowRObj = "#cke_" + editor.name + " .cke_inner "
                    + ".cke_top";
            $(overFlowRObj).addClass("cke_top_overflow");
        }
    }

    function groupLabelElementDiv(grpId, className) {
        var elementDiv = "<div id='groupLabel_" + grpId
                + "' class='groupLabel transitionType groupLabel_"
                + className + "'></div>";
        return elementDiv;
    }

    function createSubGroup() {
        var loopVar = 0;
        var divEle = '<div class="subGrpLabel textGroupLabel">' + "Font"
                + '</div>';

        /*
         * for (var k = 0; k < editor.toolbar.length; k++) { if
         * (editor.toolbar[k] != "/") { for (var l = 0; l <
         * editor.toolbar[k].items.length; l++) { if
         * (editor.toolbar[k].items[l].type == "separator") { //
         * console.log("sep") // $(editor.toolbar[k].items[l]).text("name"); } } } }
         */

    }
    editor.on('destroy', function() {
        /* alert(this.name) */
        var undoName = "undoRedoCont" + editor.name;
        $("#" + undoName).remove();

    });
    editor.on('instanceReady', function() {
        // console.log(previewSeen);
        $("#universalPreloader").addClass("displayNone");
        createMainGroups();
        createSubGroup();
        focusEvent();
        undoRedoButtonSeprator();
    });
    function undoRedoButtonSeprator() {
        var undoRedoContEle = "<div class='urcEle' id='undoRedoCont"
                + editor.name + "'></div>";
        $("#undoRedoContSetParent").append(undoRedoContEle);
        var ele = $("#" + editor.ui.instances.Undo._.id).detach();
        $("#undoRedoCont" + editor.name).append(ele);
        $(ele).addClass("cke_button_75px");
        ele = $("#" + editor.ui.instances.Redo._.id).detach();
        $("#undoRedoCont" + editor.name).append(ele);
        $(ele).addClass("cke_button_75px");
        $("#undoRedoCont" + editor.name).addClass("displayNone");

    }

    function focusEvent() {
        var editorObj = /* parent. */$("#cke_wordcount_" + editor.name);
        editorObj.addClass("displayFlexRelative").addClass("displayNone")
                .addClass("vertical-align-middle").addClass(" flexHCenter")
                .css("width", "160px");
        var undoRedoCont = /* parent. */$("#undoRedoCont" + editor.name);
        undoRedoCont.addClass("displayNone");
        editor.on('focus', function(e) {
            onFoucs(e);
        });
        editor.on('blur', function(e) {
            onBlur(e);
        });
    }

    function onBlur(e) {
        var editorObj = /* parent. */$("#cke_wordcount_" + e.editor.name);
        editorObj.addClass("displayNone");
        $("#undoRedoCont" + editor.name).addClass("displayNone");
        $("#dummyUNDOREDO").removeClass("displayNone");
        resetAllAbsolute();
        /*
         * if (e.editor.config.customInline) {
         * $("#toolbarEditorInline").addClass("displayNone"); }
         */
    }

    function onFoucs(e) {
        var editorObj = /* parent. */$("#cke_wordcount_" + e.editor.name)
        editorObj.removeClass("displayNone");
        $("#undoRedoCont" + editor.name).removeClass("displayNone");
        $("#dummyUNDOREDO").addClass("displayNone");
        /*
         * if (e.editor.config.customInline) {
         * $("#toolbarEditorInline").removeClass("displayNone"); }
         */
    }

    CKEDITOR.document.appendStyleSheet(CKEDITOR.plugins
            .getPath('grouplabel')
            + 'css/style.css');

}
});
```

Comment: How this differs from the shared space plugin?

Comment: Yes, the base is shared space but has customized to my need.